# connection refused error with Krakend api-gateway?

Tags: node.js, tcp, microservices, api-gateway, krakend

I want to see and try how does `api-gateway` work specifically I am using `Krakend`. For technically, I have a service where it only receives a request and respond back. The problem is the service which is a very simple http-server does not receive the request from the `api-gateway` when the regarding endpoint is triggered through `api-gateway`. However, when I make a get request through browser writing the exact url `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users`, I get the response. Basically, what I want is, when I make a get request to the `localhost:8099/users` which is the `api-gateway` I want api-gateway to make a get request to the **users api** and see the expected logs.

This is the error I get.

> Error #01: Get "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused

Here is my `krakend.json` file where I put the configuration.

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "host" : [
        "http://localhost:8099"
    ],
    "extra_config": {
      "github_com/devopsfaith/krakend-cors": {
        "allow_origins": [
          "*"
        ],
        "expose_headers": [
          "Content-Length"
        ],
        "max_age": "12h",
        "allow_methods": [
          "GET"
        ],
        "allow_headers": [
          "*"
        ]
      }
    },
    "timeout": "3000ms",
    "cache_ttl": "300s",
    "output_encoding": "string",
    "name": "api-gateway",
    "port": 8099,
    "read_timeout": "5s",
    "idle_timeout": "5s",
    "write_timeout": "5s",
    "read_header_timeout": "5s",
    "endpoints": [
      {
        "endpoint": "/users",
        "method" : "GET",
        "backend": [
          {
            "encoding" : "string",
            "url_pattern": "/api/v1/users",
            "method": "GET",
            "host": [
              "http://localhost:8000"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

And this is my node js server.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8099',
    methods: "GET, PUT"
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.get('/api/v1/users', (req, res) => {
    console.log('REQUEST => \n')
    console.log(req.url)
    console.log(req.hostname)
})

app.listen(8000, () => {console.log('server has started on 8000')})
```

So, when I make a get request to the address `http://localhost:8099/users` the log is as follows:

```
[GIN] 2021/06/30 - 22:44:05 | 500 |      4.8998ms |      172.17.0.1 | GET      "/users"
Error #01: Get "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8000: connect: connection refused
```

In the `Krakend` documentation here it says when status codes above 400 are returned from the backend, "I guess" the log is written as above with `500` code.

> 500 Internal Server Error Default error code, and in general, when backends return any status above 400

I did play with the `krakend.json` file and changed different parts of the file and still didn't work.

I know this is a `tcp` error checked what could be the reasons causing that error.
1- port may be crashed, which is not true because  when I make a get request directly to the endpoint `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users` I get the log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each service, the name of the container declared in the `docker-compose.yml` should match the name written in the `krakend.json` file. For instance, `user-service` should be also declared in `krakend.json` file as `http://user-service:$PORT` in the `host` field.

Comment: What does this mean? The original post doesn't appear to be using a compose file. It would also be a pain to have to rebuild a container every time he changes something.

Comment: You must use the docker container_name, but not a local IP.

`services:
        nginx:
           container_name: service-nginx
}`

Answer (score 0):

Update For V3 :

everyone might need to look into this one if you are using Version 3 krakend.json File

[Using KrakenD with local nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467741/using-krakend-with-local-nodejs-server)

Because, the above answer will throw error if we used it with newer version krakend

Comment: can you please add example files for docker-compose.yml and a krakend.json?
Still getting connection refused

Comment: For sample `krakend.json` you can refer the link I mentioned in answer. 

And I haven't used krakend with `docker-compose.yml`