# Using KrakenD with local nodejs server

Tags: node.js, api, krakend

I have a up and running nodejs server (with one API) on my local machine .

I have created the new docker container for krakend using

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 -v $PWD:/etc/krakend/ devopsfaith/krakend run --config /etc/krakend/krakend.json
```

Although, I have to make some changes in above command because I am working on windows.

I have created a krakend.json file and it's content are

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "timeout": "3s",
  "cache_ttl": "300s",
  "port": 8080,
  "default_hosts": ["http://localhost:3001"],
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/contacts",
      "output_encoding": "json",
      "extra_config": {
        "qos/ratelimit/router": {
          "max_rate": 5000
        }
      },
      "backend": [
        {
          "host": [
          "http://localhost:3001", 
          "http://cotacts:3001"
          ],
          "url_pattern": "/contacts",
          "is_collection": "true",
          "encoding": "json",
          "extra_config": {
            "backend/http": {
              "return_error_details": "backend_alias"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

But when I am hitting the url `http://localhost:8080/contacts` using postman I am getting

```
[KRAKEND] 2022/03/14 - 07:26:30.305 ▶ ERROR [ENDPOINT: /contacts] Get "http://localhost:3001/contacts": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3001: connect: connection refused
```

I found a relevant one over here
[connection refused error with Krakend api-gateway?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68202585/connection-refused-error-with-krakend-api-gateway)

but, I am not getting what to change in my case

Answer (score 5):

Inside the `backend` you have two `hosts` in the load balancer. KrakenD will try one and the other in a round-robin fashion.

```
"host": [
          "http://localhost:3001", 
          "http://cotacts:3001"
          ],
```

If you have started KrakenD as you have written in your message, then neither of the names are available.

1. `localhost` is KrakenD itself (not the host machine starting KrakenD). KrakenD does not have any port `3001` so it's expected that it cannot connect. You should write your host IP.
2. I am guessing `cotacts:3001` is some outside service. If you need to access this service by name you need to use it through a docker compose.

The problem you have is Docker connectivity, and is not related to KrakenD. KrakenD is just complaining that it cannot connect to those services.

Finally, the `"default_hosts"` is something that it does not exist in KrakenD, it makes no effect in the configuration, you can delete that line. If you want to have a default host without needing to declare it in every backend use just `host`. In summary, your configuration should look like:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://www.krakend.io/schema/v3.json",
    "version": 3,
    "timeout": "3s",
    "cache_ttl": "300s",
    "port": 8080,
    "host": [
        "http://1.2.3.4:3001"
    ],
    "endpoints": [
        {
            "endpoint": "/contacts",
            "extra_config": {
                "qos/ratelimit/router": {
                    "max_rate": 5000
                }
            },
            "backend": [
                {
                    "url_pattern": "/contacts",
                    "is_collection": "true",
                    "extra_config": {
                        "backend/http": {
                            "return_error_details": "backend_alias"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And replace `1.2.3.4` with the IP of the machine running the Node.

Comment: Might be the best answer I ever Got ! And thanks for the example

Comment: I will be more than happy to do that but sadly I am  not the author of the question