# json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []interface {}

Tags: node.js, api, gateway, krakend

I am using krakend and local nodejs server.

As per :
[Using KrakenD with local nodejs server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71467741/using-krakend-with-local-nodejs-server)

I have created the krakend and nodejs server. It is up and Running and the communication between krakend and nodejs server is properly going on. But, the api response is JSON and while giving response krakend printing

```
2022/03/15 02:54:06 KRAKEND ERROR: [ENDPOINT: /contacts] json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []interface {}
```

Although I have already added the flag `is_collection: "true"`  in krankend (as shown here)
https://github.com/luraproject/lura/issues/216

But still it is throwing the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to get it done via removing the flag

```
"is_collection": "true",
```

and instead add the flag

```
"encoding": "json"
```

I don't know what is the issue while parsing the response type but I guess it an issue with Go build or something else

Comment: It's working for me